# SQL Tuple Comparison in EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

### Question

Is it possible to do a [SQL Tuple Comparison](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/comparison/tuple_comparison.html) using LINQ with EF Core in C#?

### More Info

Expected SQL Result

```sql
SELECT * FROM Locations
WHERE (Locations.Id,Locations.Created) >= ("08d85dba-eb22-4fb4-8868-f833a1403bec","2020-09-20 23:09:55.885263")
ORDER BY Locations.Created 
LIMIT 10;
```

What I care about specifically is the `WHERE` clause expression which I am referring to as [Tuple Comparison](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/comparison/tuple_comparison.html)

```sql
WHERE (Locations.Id,Locations.Created) >= ("08d85dba-eb22-4fb4-8868-f833a1403bec","2020-09-20   23:09:55.885263")
```

I have tried multiple things using LINQ but the C# compiler always ends up failing because of the `>=` operator and C# not knowing how to compare it.

### Reason

I am trying to do a [Tuple Comparison](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/comparison/tuple_comparison.html) to implement cursor based pagination from this [post](http://morningcoffee.io/stable-pagination.html).

*For now I will be using a stored procedure, I am just wondering if it is possible*

Comment: *always ends up failing*. Isn't that the answer? I don't think EF will invest in features that are not supported by SQL Server (both from Microsoft, would be too embarrassing). Also, I think the mismatch in supported operators between C# and SQL is a major hurdle.

Comment: Will this not work in your case `Locations.Id == "08d85dba-eb22-4fb4-8868-f833a1403bec" && Locations.Created  >= "2020-09-20 23:09:55.885263"`

Comment: On a side note. Why would you want to compare if a guid is equal or larger than another guid? I guess it makes sense if they are sequential, but then the creation date would be enough on itself.

Comment: @GertArnold That is based on my knowledge of LINQ, C#, and SQL, just wanted see if anyone had a way of doing that I didn't know. What you said makes sense though. I am also not a SQL expert and not sure what Tuple Comparison translates to in SQL.Is it something unique or is it shorthand for something?

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty if you look at the post http://morningcoffee.io/stable-pagination.html (at the end) of the question  the Tuple Comparison is not equivalent to what you wrote as the result will return multiple rows where what you wrote will always return a single row because of `Locations.Id == "08d85dba-eb22-4fb4-8868-f833a1403bec"`

Comment: @NicholasMata it's shorthand. `(a, b) >= (1, 2)` is basically the same as `a > 1 OR (a == 1 AND b >= 2)`. Although I'm not sure how tuples behave with index strategies.

Comment: @404 Thanks for the comment was very helpful and I was able to solve my problem thanks to it. :]

Comment: @NicholasMata you're asking a very wrong question. EF is an ORM, not a data access library. It's used to make working with *objects* easier and *abstract* the underlying SQL dialect. All ORMs are leaky in that respect, but you ended up leaking a specific dialect into the client. Why use an ORM, much less EF, at *all* in this case?

Comment: @NicholasMata as for `to implement cursor based pagination `  SQL is a set based language. Cursors exist mainly for compatibility with 30-year old file based data access. Luckily, that article *doesn't* use cursors at all, despite the name.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the advice as I said at the end of my post I will be using a stored procedure. As for your first comment, I typically like to do everything in EF LINQ initially and then as performance is needed translate to SQL Views or Stored Proc. Not sure your second comment applies as the cursor based pagination is for a WebApi implementation as stated in the post http://morningcoffee.io/stable-pagination.html that relies on the Tuple Comparison when primary key is UUID/GUID.

Comment: You're using EF wrong then. It's an ORM, not ADO.NET. And cursors have a very specific meaning in databases, [including MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html). There are no `DECLARE CURSOR` nor any `FETCH` statements in that article.

Comment: Although the article does describe something like the client-side cursors used by VB6 - it returns the record IDs to the client and the client retrieves pages of rows using them. Despite the assertions, it suffers from data modification issues, just like using `OFFSET` and `FETCH`. A record *can* change or get deleted between calls, modifying the results. You'd need an explicit transaction to ensure the results didn't change throughout the paging operation, which is definitely a bad idea and simply not doable with HTTP APIs

Comment: That is because the post is a theoretical implementation of how one can implement cursor based pagination for a WEBAPI as stated in previous comment. Similar to the following https://slack.engineering/evolving-api-pagination-at-slack

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Replying to "it suffers from data modification issues, just like using OFFSET and FETCH" -- It's not that data can't change between skipping pages, it's that the results you show are consistent in the sense that you won't return any repeats if new items are inserted between page queries or skip anything in case items are deleted. And unlike OFFSET, you are completely immune to the common scenario of only insertions before page 1 and only deletions at the end. Plus there's the whole scalability thing: OFFSET needs to linearly count all the records before the requested page.

Comment: @relatively_random unless some records are deleted. All those techniques have been used and exhaustively investigated in the last 30+ years, with all pitfalls identified and far better solutions than hand-rolled cursors, eg database snapshots, using separate databases for OLTP and reporting , *persisted report results* and combinations of the above. Reporting Services for example stores snapshots of a report's data since it was first released, just like all other server-side report tools. That's really stable, more scaleable (no locks on the source tables) and allows reuse

Comment: @relatively_random in fact, using `id>lastId` was the technique used *before* `OFFSET` was introduced. It's faster but only works if there's a usable unique and *indexed* field in the output. Even then, it still impacts the OLTP database. APIs with really large datasets usually require (or perform themselves) a call to produce a snapshot of the results and only then start sending them in pages.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Truly not my area of expertise so I won't disagree with anything you said, but given just the two alternatives (OFFSET vs skipping with WHERE), it seems like OFFSET provides only one advantage: simplicity. Assuming you _do_ have usable fields and index, of course.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "unless some records are deleted" -- in my original comment, I literally said that even with deleted records, you'll still have consistent pages in the sense that nothing gets skipped. Unlike with OFFSET, which will skip over entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@404](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9034195/404)'s comment I was able to run some tests and write a LINQ expression

#### Solution

```cs
var someDate = new DateTime("2020-09-23 12:40:58");
query.Where(l => l.Created >= someDate && (string.CompareTo(l.Id, "1bb50ac7-4d8e-4493-9b15-e1997a") >= 0 || l.Created >= someDate));
```

NOTE: I need to verify the sql outputted by this statement but to my knowledge this should work according to [Unsupported System.String Non-static Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/system-string-methods?redirectedfrom=MSDN#unsupported-systemstring-non-static-methods)

#### SQL Validation

Lets say I have a table called Locations with the following data.

```
[
    {"id": "1b859e3c-d512-47e4-8ef0-106165", "created": "2020-09-23 12:38:34"},
    {"id": "1bb50ac7-4d8e-4493-9b15-e1997a", "created": "2020-09-23 12:40:58"},
    {"id": "35626ffe-d84e-4543-8734-89dbda", "created": "2020-09-22 12:40:58"},
    {"id": "ada06b5f-a9ca-4bc3-9b61-105e89", "created": "2020-09-25 12:40:58"},
    {"id": "c34b21d1-19ea-48b9-bee8-f201d6", "created": "2020-09-23 12:40:58"},
    {"id": "f68064c7-6617-46c4-b19c-e70b25", "created": "2020-09-23 12:38:33"}
]
```

Ordered Results

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Locations
ORDER BY Locations.created ASC, Locations.id ASC;
-- Results
-- [
--     {"id": "35626ffe-d84e-4543-8734-89dbda", "created": "2020-09-22 12:40:58"},
--     {"id": "f68064c7-6617-46c4-b19c-e70b25", "created": "2020-09-23 12:38:33"},
--     {"id": "1b859e3c-d512-47e4-8ef0-106165", "created": "2020-09-23 12:38:34"},
--     {"id": "1bb50ac7-4d8e-4493-9b15-e1997a", "created": "2020-09-23 12:40:58"},
--     {"id": "c34b21d1-19ea-48b9-bee8-f201d6", "created": "2020-09-23 12:40:58"},
--     {"id": "ada06b5f-a9ca-4bc3-9b61-105e89", "created": "2020-09-25 12:40:58"}
-- ]
```

Tuple Comparison

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Location
WHERE (Location.created, Location.id) >= ("2020-09-23 12:40:58", "1bb50ac7-4d8e-4493-9b15-e1997a")
ORDER BY Location.created ASC, Location.id ASC
LIMIT 4;
-- Results
-- [
--     {"id": "1bb50ac7-4d8e-4493-9b15-e1997a", "created": "2020-09-23 12:40:58"},
--     {"id": "c34b21d1-19ea-48b9-bee8-f201d6", "created": "2020-09-23 12:40:58"},
--     {"id": "ada06b5f-a9ca-4bc3-9b61-105e89", "created": "2020-09-25 12:40:58"}
-- ]
```

Longhand purposed by [@404](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9034195/404)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Location
WHERE Location.created >= "2020-09-23 12:40:58" AND  (Location.id >= "1bb50ac7-4d8e-4493-9b15-e1997a" OR Location.created >= "2020-09-23 12:40:58")
ORDER BY Location.created ASC, Location.id ASC
LIMIT 4;
-- Results
-- [
--     {"id": "1bb50ac7-4d8e-4493-9b15-e1997a", "created": "2020-09-23 12:40:58"},
--     {"id": "c34b21d1-19ea-48b9-bee8-f201d6", "created": "2020-09-23 12:40:58"},
--     {"id": "ada06b5f-a9ca-4bc3-9b61-105e89", "created": "2020-09-25 12:40:58"}
-- ]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem correct. It basically checks for Location.created only. If Location.craeted >= x, then (Location.id >= y OR Location.created >= x) is always true. I think you need to have a > instead of >= in that last comparison.